# Does a date fall ON or Between two dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

So I been fighting with this code for a few days, scouring the page and google for some answers and I thought I had it nailed.  Today I found out I was wrong about ONE date...and I can't see to solve it.  I'll try to explain what I'm doing then post some snippets and see if we can put our collective heads together and solve this one.

I work for a Major Hospitality Brand, and our owners have certain Booking Windows for hotels.  Platinum Members can book between 45-days and 10 months, and non-platinum can only book 2 months to 10 months (in this case just months, not 60 days).  So I have a date calculator that calculates the different time frames based on TODAY()

[image: Points Booking Window]

We also have a spot where you can put in a date the owner is requesting, which evaluates the booking window for the owner

[image: Date Calculator]

Ultimately the goal is to have a section on the side that will show my users IF the date entered in Date Calculator is eligible for both owner types to book or not.

[image: To Book or Not to Book...that is the question]

The formula I am using is this:

Non-Platinum: `=IF(AND(F3>$F$19,F3<$F$20),"OK to Book","Not Ok to Book")`

Platinum: `=IF(AND(F3>=$F$19,F3<=$F$21),"Ok to Book","Not Ok to Book")`

If I enter a date that is clearly outside the range, it works fine.  The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to compare a date that falls ON one of the extremes

UPDATE: Here is a link to an excel sheet that I made with the data I'm working on
[DateCalculator](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jADVjuucFFRwFOl6V5Nm3Je9027c4Y_D/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: what is in F3, F19 and F20 and F21?

Comment: Supposed that might help...lol
F3 = Today
F19 = 10 Months from the Requested Date (2nd image)
F20 = 2 Months from Requested Date
F21 = 45 Days from Requested Date

Comment: There's probably an issue with your comparison, but your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: one note is you are using >= for platinum equation, but only > for non-platinum

Comment: Lemme pull the calculator and formulas out into a seperate excel and upload that to play with!!  thanks for the tip @RonRosenfeld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your uploaded workbook, and considering that the tables might be in different positions on your real workbook, I made some changes:

- B2:  =TODAY()

  - =NOW() which you had in there, includes the time
- Your references to cells and your equality operators both seem incorrect, even taking into account what you wrote about the contents of column `f` in you comment above.
- To clarify things, I created named references:

---

```
_10_MONTHS     refers to:   =Sheet1!$B$6
_2_MONTHS      refers to:   =Sheet1!$B$5
_45_DAYS       refers to:   =Sheet1!$B$4
REQUESTED_DATE refers to:   =Sheet1!$B$13
```

Then use these formula, adjusting the equality operator as you wish:

```
NON-PLAT:  =IF(AND(REQUESTED_DATE>=_2_MONTHS,REQUESTED_DATE<=_10_MONTHS),"OK to Book","Not Ok to Book")
PLAT:     =IF(AND(REQUESTED_DATE>=_45_DAYS,REQUESTED_DATE<=_10_MONTHS),"OK to Book","Not Ok to Book")
```

Oh, I also changed your calculation formulas to use simple addition and/or edate, depending on the results.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

This should get you started as to how to approach your "real" workbook.

Comment: Awesome!  I will work on implementing your suggested changes as soon as I can.  I do this in my spare time.  So thank you SO much for your effort and assistance!!